# Carousel in HTML not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I dont know why this code doesn't work... since i am a beginner i couldn't find whats wrong with this,Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me out

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Jothidhal</title>
       <meta charset = "utf-8">
       <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width" ,  initial-scale = 1>
       <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "additional.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal:700" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class = "container-fluid">
         <div id = "My_Carousel" class = "carousel-slide" data-ride = "carousel">
           <ol class = "carousel-indicators">
           <li data-target = "#My_Carousel" data-slide-to = "0" class = "active"> </li>
           <li data-target = "#My_Carousel" data-slide-to = "1" > </li>
           <li data-target = "#My_Carousel" data-slide-to = "2" > </li>
           </ol>
           <div class = "carousel-inner" role ="listbox">
             <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 1.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"</div>
             <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 2.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"</div>
             <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 3.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"</div>
             <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 4.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"</div>
             <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 5.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"</div>
             <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 6.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"</div>
           </div>
           <a class = "left-carousel-control" href = "#My_Carousel" role= "button" data-slide = "prev">
           <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
           <span class = "sr-only">Previous</span>
           </a> 
         </div>
       </div>
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It does help with describing what happens rather then just it does not work :)

Comment: What are errors you got?

Comment: Actually sir, am not getting the output,none of the images are getting displayed, am confused!

Comment: Remove the spaces in the file names !

Comment: You did some mistake with your edits..

Answer (score 1):

You have done some mistake with your copy & paste. This should be your html:

- Change `carousel-slide` to `carousel slide`
- Add `active` class to your first slide
- Use correct Carousel control instead of your wrong ones. The classes for the control should be `left carousel-control` and not `left-carousel-control`
- Close your `img` tags
- If you have 3 indicators, you should only have 3 slides

  ```
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="My_Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#My_Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> </li>
              <li data-target="#My_Carousel" data-slide-to="1" > </li>
              <li data-target="#My_Carousel" data-slide-to="2" > </li>
          </ol>

          <div class = "carousel-inner" role ="listbox">
              <div class = "item active"><img src = "images/images 1.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" /></div>
              <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 2.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" /></div>
              <div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 3.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" /></div>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#My_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#My_Carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
      </div>
  </div>
  ```

Check this [W3Schools tut](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) and check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z2jz09nt/4/)

If you copy paste code, at least do it right..

Answer (score 0):

Your `img` tags are not closed !

```
<div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 6.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"</div>
```

Should be

```
<div class = "item"><img src = "images/images 6.jpg" alt = "Durairaj" width = "100%" height = "400px"></div>
```

Comment: Well, first of all, there should be a space between carousel and slide (`class="carousel slide"`).
Then, remove height and width from your `img` and put that in css. Images only support int values, such as `height="400"`.